# Maximal number of boxes packed in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, 3d, sequence, packing, box

Hello Stack Overflow community!

I've been trying to come up with an algorithm that takes n boxes as input with unknown dimensions for width, height and depth and outputs the maximal number of these boxes that can be packed in a sequence. In order to pack a box into another a box needs to have a smaller width, lenght and depth. You can also tilt the boxes in any way you want in order to make them fit. However they must be axis aligned.

I thought i had come up with a solution where I sorted all boxes on volume and then tried to pack every box in a sequence in a fashion similiar to selection sort, but selection "pack" i guess. In which i tried to pack the box with the lowest dimension into the next one that is larger, etc. Then i tried the second box and tried to pack all those who were larger. Anyway I'm stuck and would really appreciate some help!

Great thanks!

Comment: "Fits into" is a partial order, and then a breadth-first search from the minimal boxes finds the longest chain.

Comment: Interesting! I'm thinking that maybe I can represent the problem as a directed graph in which each node is a box, and each edge represents "is packable in". And then simply find the longest path?

Comment: "is packable in" is not so easy though. For example, does a box of size 170x1x1 fit inside a box of size 100x100x100?

Comment: @Anonymous The question specifies an axis-aligned packing.

Comment: Hmm no the 170x1x1 would not fit inside the 100x100x100 one. The dimensions need to be less, or in such a way that we can tilt the box to make it fit.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Using the word "tilt" is a bit ambiguous...  To me, "tilting" is usually just a few degrees, which suggests that you *aren't* limiting yourself to 90-degree rotations.

Comment: I don't think it's so clear from the question whether the boxes must be axis aligned or not.

Comment: Yes they need to be axis aligned, I added it now!

Comment: They are randomly generated, so we can not know on forehand their dimensions.